# Using Nodemailer and HTML - loop inside the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, nodemailer

I'm writing a function using Nodemailer to send an email from my code,
I designed an HTML code inside my code and I want to go through a map and sending its values.

This is my function:
I wrote inside the script tag how I want it to work, but of course, it's not working.

```
async function sendAlerts(market: any, messages: string) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'mcd.nodemailer@gmail.com',
            pass: envs.emailPassword
        }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'mcd.nodemailer@gmail.com',
        to: envs.alertReceivers,
        subject: `Snowflake alert - ${market}`,
        html: `<div style='background-color:powderblue; text-align:center;'>
                <h1>Snowflake alert - ${market}</h1>
                <h2>:The following queries in ${market} returned results that are not 0\n</h2>
                </div>
                <div id='queries'><div>
                <script>
                let failedQueries ='', i;
                for (i=0; i<= ${messages.length}; i++) {
                failedQueries = failedQueries + <b>Alert Message: ${Object.keys(messages[i])} Query: ${Object.values(messages[i])} </b>;
                }
                document.getElementById('queries').innerHTML = failedQueries;
                </script>
                `
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Failed to send email due to: ' + error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
      }
```

Comment: Object.keys() and Object.values() takes an object  and returns arrays, However messages is a string, and not an object, so you cant do Object.keys(messages). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, the `market` parameter should be of type string

Comment: messages is not an array so you can't index it

Comment: @Norse messages is an object (you can ignore the type)
i'm trying to add this loop to the HTML code but I'm not sure if i can write the loop this way in script tag because it's not working.
But the code inside the script tag is working.

Comment: Well, no, you have explicitly set the type of messages to string

Comment: If you do Object.keys(<some string>) it gives you ['0']

Comment: but it works because it's an object. 
The problem here is the syntax of the code inside the script tag @Norse

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Maybe the script tag doesn't know about the messages variable, so maybe you have to say `<script>let messages = ${messages}</script>`, and you also forgot to put quotes around the stuff in the for loop. There should be quotes around `<b>...</b>`

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are trying to do is maybe something like this

```
async function sendAlerts(market: string, messages: {message: string, query: string}[]) {
  ...
  var mailOptions = {
      from: 'mcd.nodemailer@gmail.com',
      to: envs.alertReceivers,
      subject: `Snowflake alert - ${market}`,
      html: `<div style='background-color:powderblue; text-align:center;'>
            <h1>Snowflake alert - ${market}</h1>
            <h2>:The following queries in ${market} returned results that are not 0\n</h2>
            </div>
            <div id='queries'><div>
            <script>
            let failedQueries ='', i;
            for (i=0; i<= ${messages.length}; i++) {
            failedQueries = failedQueries + <b>Alert Message: ${messages[i].message} Query: ${messages[i].query} </b>;
            }
            document.getElementById('queries').innerHTML = failedQueries;
            </script>
            `
  };
  ...
}
```